# Blender with C# instead of Python

Tags: c#, blender

Like you can see in the title I want to know if it's possible to use C# or any other language instead of Python for Blender.

Comment: Probably yes: but I guess your *actual* question is "how to achieve this", and here the answer is clearly "that´s too broad for a question on stack. Furthermore questions about tutorials and documentation are off-topic." Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Unfortunatly no, the scripting interface is Python only. But you can still use C# Lib with Python to interconnect them. I will recommend asking https://blender.stackexchange.com they may have the information you need to help you do it in Py.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from [blender.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20150903012742/http://www.blender.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=15508):

> The scripting interface is only for Python. If you are interested in
> digging in the source code, then you may have some usage for C++ too.
> The main source is coded in C, but as I know C++ is used in some parts
> of Game Engine. You can download the source code from Blender's
> homepage, and see if you can follow it. (Personally I do not.)
>
> There are some interesting closely related projects coded in C++, if I
> remember right, MakeHuman is one such. This may be the environment
> most interesting for you if you want to keep using C++.
>
> Blender supports many fileformats for importing and exporting models.
> Some of them can be utilized in your own projects, as I know, quite
> easily by C++. In this case you would use Blender for modelling your
> meshes and C++ for writing your own interface utilising your models.
>
> Yet still, be open for new ideas. C++ is quite oldfashioned
> programming language, complex, not very readable. That's the main
> reason why people today prefer Python.

So your answer is no. there might be a support for c++ (the source code indicates so) but no support for C#.

Comment: Actually, you "can" by shoehorning Python.NET to load your .NET assembly, and then offload as much work as possible into it. If that's meaningful is another question.